# plot opens in browser, I would rather open it in a dedicated window

Tags: matplotlib, plot, python-3.6

I have a very silly problem.

A colleague passed me an imshow plot that opens a window in my web browser. The problem is that I get this error and is crashing the debugger.

```
Press Ctrl+C to stop WebAgg server
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

First of all, I press Crl+C and nothing happens. I'm using pycharm debugger.

I'm an old fashioned guy and I would rather just open the chart on a dedicated window, no browser involved. I've been dealing with this issue for hours and I officially give up. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to change the backend to TkAgg? `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')`

Comment: Thanks. That did it.

Comment: I have the same problem but using matplotlib.use('TkAgg') only blocks the process but does not show a window - Edit: Also setting plt.interactive(False) did the trick. I wonder why we have to go through this all of a sudden.